# Angular conditional confirm dialog - How to avoid writing redundant code?

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog, observable, angular12

I need a simple confirm dialog where the user has to either click "Yes" or "No". I wrote a simple dialog component to do this with the following code:

**confirmation-dialog-component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material/dialog";

@Component({
  selector: "app-confirmation-dialog",
  templateUrl: "./confirmation-dialog.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./confirmation-dialog.component.scss"],
})
export class ConfirmationDialogComponent {
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmationDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public text: string,
  ) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(false);
  }

  onYesClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  }
}
```

**confirmation-dialog-component.html:**

```
<div class="dialog-title">
  <h2>Confirmation</h2>
  <button mat-icon-button class="close-button" (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>

<div mat-dialog-content>
  <span>{{ text }}</span>
</div>

<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button type="button" mat-button color="accent" (click)="onNoClick()">
    No
  </button>
  <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onYesClick()">
    Yes
  </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

If I want the user to confirm something, I can use the dialog like this:

```
const confirmDialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      data: "Do you really want to do this?",
});

confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmResult) => {
  if (confirmResult === true) {
    // User confirmed the dialog
  }
});
```

Now I have a situation where I only need to show the confirmation dialog under certain conditions. Back when I was still writing WinForms applications in C#, I could easily show a confirmation dialog like this:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to do this?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
   // User confirmed the dialog
}
```

This would allow me to easily skip showing the confirmation dialog under certain conditions:

```
if (showConfirmationDialog == false || MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to do this?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
   // Continue
}
```

How can I do something similar with my own confirmation dialog? I cannot just show it under certain conditions because if I have to show it, I need to move my code which should be executed if the user clicks "Yes" into the subscribe. However, if the condition is true so I do not need to show the dialog, I do not need the subscribe. This forces me to have two places in my code where I need to write what should happen after the user clicks "Yes" or if the condition is true. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Why is there a vote for closing my question with the reason "Needs more focus"? I am asking exactly **one** question: How can I avoid writing the same code twice, in the subscribe and if the condition is true?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use an observable stream to track your condition and show/not show the dialog based on that.

Say, for instance, you are calling a function `showDialog()` that returns a boolean/promise/observable, that then decides whether or not to show the dialog, you can create an observable from that:

```
showDialog(): boolean{
    let showDialog = true
    // Determine whether to show
    return showDialog
}
```

Then create an observable from that and pipe it down the stream.

```
// Imports
import {of} from 'rxjs'

// somewhere in your class implementation 

of(showDialog())
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((show: boolean): [boolean, any] =>{
      if(show) return [of(show), this.openDialog()]
      else return [of(show), {}]
    })
  )
.subscribe(([dialogWasShown, result])=>{
  if(dialogWasShown){
    // do something with the result
  }
  else {
    // do something else
  }
})
```

In the above case, you have your condition determining whether or not to show the dialog.